# 'float' object is not iterable for arabic_reshaper.reshape

Tags: python-3.x, display

i had this scripte show error when run

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import arabic_reshaper
res2 = {get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(k)): v for k,v in bow1.items()}
data = pd.DataFrame(res2.items(),columns=['Word','frequency']).sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False)
data =data.head(100)
p=sns.barplot(x='Word',y='frequency',data=data )
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 8)
```

Error code:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4255b5273424> in <module>
      1 from bidi.algorithm import get_display
      2 import arabic_reshaper
----> 3 res2 = {get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(k)): v for k,v in bow1.items()}
      4 data = pd.DataFrame(res2.items(),columns=['Word','frequency']).sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False)
      5 data =data.head(100)

<ipython-input-15-4255b5273424> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 from bidi.algorithm import get_display
      2 import arabic_reshaper
----> 3 res2 = {get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(k)): v for k,v in bow1.items()}
      4 data = pd.DataFrame(res2.items(),columns=['Word','frequency']).sort_values(by='frequency',ascending=False)
      5 data =data.head(100)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arabic_reshaper/arabic_reshaper.py in reshape(self, text)
    123                          if use_unshaped_instead_of_isolated else ISOLATED)
    124 
--> 125         for letter in text:
    126             if HARAKAT_RE.match(letter):
    127                 if not delete_harakat:

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

it is should display word frequncey

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.